# Error compiling phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap-cli

I'm trying to get up to Google Play but I'm in trouble already follow all ta here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

But still will not. Speaks on Google Play:

> Você enviou um APK não assinado. Crie um APK assinado

The terminal executing this command:

> jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs android-debug-unaligned.apk

Message appears:

> jar verified.
>
> Warning:  This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not
>   validated. This jar contains signatures that does not include a
>   timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this
>   jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2046-01-20) or
>   after any future revocation date.

Comment: Are you using CLI (Command Line Interface)? Like: `cordova add android`?

Comment: You have the wrong tag. You wanted `phonegap-cli`. *Phonegap Build* is a cloud based service by Adobe/Phongap. Best of Luck.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it you are trying to submit your app built in debug mode.

Before you sign your app, you have to build it in release mode :

```
cordova build android -release
```

this will create a file **android-release-unsigned.apk**. This is the file you have to use for signing & submission.